# Error #200 when adding comments on friends post

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I get error #200 when trying to add some comments on friends post:

```
{
   "name": "Comment", 
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/586953601/posts/10151621828953602"
},

D/Facebook-Util(11192): POST URL: https://graph.facebook.com/10151621828953602/comments


D/(11192): Facebook {"error":{"message":"(#200) Permissions error","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}
```

I have set permissions in order to do this: `publish_stream` and `publish_actions`. Do I also need to set `offline_access` permission?

I am building this app using sdk version 3.0.2.

Why can't I add comments?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have offline_access permission anymore, It is depericiated, I believe your token doesn't have the permissions which you said you have, just cross check, this is how you can verify:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<YOUR FACEBOOK USER ID HERE>/permissions?access_token=<YOUR ACCESS TOKEN HERE>
```

Above link will show you the permissions of your access token.

Also are you UTF-8 Encoding your comment which you are posting on facebook?

Hope this helps.

Cheers,

Reno Jones

Comment: im retrive permissons on evry login :) and im realy have it

Comment: "publish_stream": 1,
         "publish_actions": 1,

Comment: And i will try convert my comment to UTF-8, maybe this is my problem!

Comment: UTF-8 was nat helpful

Comment: Can you share the code you have written to for posting a comment?

Comment: Great thats nice.. :)

Comment: but sometimes its happend again :(

Comment: there could be a bug in the sdk itself? you can report it on facebook developers.